# How to calculate most visited pages excluding destination page visits on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way to calculate:

```
Pages visits (excluding) Visits as destination page?
```

And perhaps show a chart like this:

```
| Page X | Navigation visits = Total page visits - Destination page visits |

| PAGE C | 200 = 300 - 100 |
| PAGE A | 150 = 200 - 50  |
| PAGE B | 100 = 400 - 300 |
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Behavior --> Site Content --> All pages` you can see:

**Pageviews**, the total number of pages viewed. Repeated views of a single page are counted.

**Entrances**, the number of times visitors entered your site through a specified page or set of pages.

So you can get you values in this way: `Pageviews - Entrances`

Comment: What's the procedure to show data with this subtraction in Google Analytics?

Comment: Is there a difference between Destination page and Entrances?

Comment: There are no difference between Landing pages and Entrances (to see it, just compare the number of sessions in Landing pages with the entrances for the same pages). There is no way to obtain the value you want directly in Google Analytics however you have everything you need to calculate it.